# What is the probability of getting at least one more head from two coin flips than one coin flip?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, recreational-mathematics

Let's say that I have two fair coins and my opponent has one fair coin. Me and my opponent can flip each of our coins once. I win only if I get at least one more head than my opponent. What is the probability of me winning?

I don't understand how to think about this problem in terms of the probabilities. The event of me getting at least one head from the two coin flips is $$P(TH) + P(HH) = 0.5 + 0.25 = 0.75 $$ while the probability of my opponent getting at least one head is  $$ P(H) = 0.5.$$ I am confused by contrasting my opponents probability of winning with mine. How would I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first two flips are yours and the third is your opponent's you get 8 possible outcomes: $HH\ H, HH\ T,\ldots, TT\ T$, each with probability $1/8$

To have at least one head more than your opponent, you need either 2 heads vs opponent's 0 or 1 heads or 1 head vs opponent's 0 heads, so the favorable outcomes are:

$HH\ H, HH\ T, HT\ T, TH\ T$.

So probability of winning is $4/8=1/2$

Or you can use independence:

$$P(\text{winning})=P(\text{you 2 heads, opponent 1 head})+P(\text{you 2 heads, opponent 0 heads})+P(\text{you 1 head, opponent 0 heads})\\=P(\text{you 2 heads})P(\text{opponent 1 head})+P(\text{you 2 heads})P(\text{opponent 0 heads})+P(\text{you 1 head})P(\text{opponent 0 heads})\\=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Great, this makes sense! If we wanted to solve this problem by using a formula, would we use the combinatorics formula?

Comment: I added a solution using formula.

Comment: But why is the P(you 2 head, opponent 0 heads) is not considered in your formula?

Comment: Because you only win if you get one more head than your opponent, not two more.

Comment: But getting two heads, while opponent gets none is still a possibility if we evaluate results after both tosses are complete.

Comment: ... so make it clear: does two heads against none count as a win? Your problem says "win only if I get one more head than my opponent", so I assumed it doesn't.

Comment: You helped me realize that wording matters, my fault. I meant to say "win by at least one head". I will edit the question... This changes will change the answer. I wish @true blue anil did not delete his answer!

Comment: I updated my answer. You can also compress the first two probabilities to $P(\text{you 2 heads})$, since in this case you win regardless of what opponent flips.

Answer (score 1):

$\underline{Answer\; for\; you\; getting\; at\; least\; one\; more\; head}$

Consider that initially, you both toss only one coin.

*You can win only if you have already won, or are equal and win with your second toss.*

Denoting your results in caps, and opponents in lowercase for clarity,

P(you win) = P(Ht) + P(HhH) + P(TtH) = $\dfrac12 + \dfrac14 + \dfrac14 = \dfrac12$

---

**Added material**

Interestingly, if you toss **(n+1)** coins against **n** tossed by your opponent, P(You win) is still $\dfrac12$

After tossing $n$ coins each, let $p$ be the probability that you are **ahead**.  By symmetry, $p$ is also the probability that your opponent is ahead, and the probability of a tie is $1-2p$. You have just two ways to win:  either you are ahead before the last toss, or there is a tie and you then get $H$.

Thus P(You win) $= p + (1-2p)\cdot\frac 12 = p+\frac 12 -p =\frac 12$

Comment: But what if you don't care about the order and just look at the results after all tosses are complete?

Comment: We are **not** caring about order, we are just delaying tossing your coin 2 (or delaying declaring its result) , to enable the situation to be seen clearly.

Comment: I am adding some more material .

Comment: OK, but what if we **did not** delay the tossing and evaluated the results at the end? Then we would have to consider P(HHt), P(HHh) and P(THt)? You brought up a very good point on timing when we evaluate the win.

Comment: Will it affect the results if we label one of your coins **1** and one of them **2** ?  I have added material that explains your win probability remains 1/2 even if you have $(n+1)$ coins against your opponent's $n$. I think it should make it very clear.